# Compiz effects in Unity 2D

Tags: compiz, unity-2d

If my GPU can process basic Compiz effects as seen in GNOME Classic, will they work in Unity 2D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I found out (after reactivating Compiz, `compiz --replace`), those effects are indeed functional within Unity 2D.

Answer (score 5):

Probably. The goal of Unity 2d is to provide a unity-like desktop to those whose "hardware platforms cannot currently support Unity's OpenGL requirements". Check their wiki page for more info: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity2D.

Comment: I already found and answered myself. Thanks for the link.