# How to enable compiz effects in Unity 2d?

Tags: 11.04, unity-2d

I run unity on ubuntu 11.04 and ive seen people with effects on the version but I cant enable it because they removed the effects settings , any help?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/50670/compiz-effects-in-unity-2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test`, please? This will tell if effects are currently supported.
If they are, you can enable them using `compiz --replace` (ALT+F2). If they're not, check if there are any restricted drivers available, enable them, reboot, and try again.

Comment: ok but when i say that the effects settyng are gone i mean the ones in  in appearance were u decide weather to have a normal desktop,moderate,or extra effects

Comment: I know you meant those, and they have been removed in 11.04. That's why I said just to try `compiz --replace` to enable them :p If it works, you can install `ccsm` to configure compiz.

Comment: i did the command and what ahppend is that all o my window borders dishapeared so i coudnt move them ore close them eccept for the quit command

Comment: Ok, so that didn't work. Any drivers showing up in `jockey` (the "Restricted/Additional hardware drivers" dialog)?

Comment: nope, this is an acer aspire one netbook and persay i do not have that much hardware installed on the machine

Comment: There appear to be many people who've managed to get it working on an Acer Aspire One, though I don't see any instructions on how to enable it, wich usually means it should work out of the box :s

Comment: :P i actually figured thnat out like 2 weeks ago and thats kinda the reason why im here x) it was a very wierd thing that i couldnt consideryng that unity "runs" on compiz

Comment: Yeah, Unity does. But Unity 2D doesn't ;p

Comment: and u tell me that now?! xDD ok ok , thanx RobinJ